# How to find the directional derivatives of these two functions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image: Photo of equations and my solutions]

So I've been given these two functions, as well as the points and vectors. I am supposed to find the directional derivatives of said functions at the point in the direction of the given vector. The formula I have received to do so is included at the bottom of the photo. Could anyone tell me why I have gotten these questions wrong, and how I can change my work or anything to fix these?

Comment: It's often expected to use the unit vector $u = v/|v|$ rather than $v$ itself when calculating the directional derivative. Typically when I see a vector $u$ it's a unit vector and given the notation you're using that seems plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the directional derivative is defined using unit vectors. So in your first question you have $v=\langle -6,8\rangle$, and then 
$$
u=\frac1{\sqrt{(-6)^2+8^2}}\,\langle -6,8\rangle=\left\langle -\frac35,\frac45\right\rangle.
$$